# How to use MongoDB/ Mongoose.js to query a OR/AND-like condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I create a query using Node.js/JavaScript, MongoDB/Mongoosejs to input a OR/AND-like query condition and receive one or more results?

Something like the following:

```
User.find({_id: idA OR idB}, function (err, users) {
  console.log(users[0]); // Is user with idA
  console.log(users[1]); // Is user with idB
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Start here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator which is a simplified kind of [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) that suits this case:

```
User.find({ "_id": { "$in": [idA,idB] } },function(err,users) {
    // results here
});
```

Essentially the same as this:

```
User.find({ "$or": [{ "_id": idA },{ "_id": idB}] },function(err,users) {
    // results here
});
```

Comment: Will the result structure differ in one or the other?

Comment: @CMPSoares No. They are logically the same. `$in` is the shorthand operation for the same logical comparison. See the documentation in the links provided.